# Paypal PLUS - preselect any other payment method that "none" or "paypal"

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

my payment wall has the following methods to choose from:

- Paypal
- Lastschrift // (bank account)
- Kreditkarte // (credit card)

The Paypal PLUS [Integration Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/de_DE/downloads/PayPal-PLUS-IntegrationGuide.pdf) says:

> preselection : "none", "paypal", "Vorkasse" synonyms (defaults to "paypal")
>
> • Determines if one of the following should be preselected:
>   nothing (="none"),
>   PayPal Wallet (="paypal") or
>   thirdparty method with methodName "Vorkasse" (or one of its synonyms).

Does anyone know how to select Lastschrift or Kreditkarte as default method?
Since these two are not "thirdparty methods" i cant select them by ="Lastschrift".

here is the payment wall code:

```
<div id="ppplus"> </div>
<script type="application/javascript">
   var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
   "approvalUrl": "<?php echo $approval_url; ?>",
   "placeholder": "ppplus",
   "mode": "sandbox",
   "country": "DE",
   "language": "de_DE",
   "preselection" : "none"
});
```